# APNS stop a notification when is received

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing a chat using APNS.

My question is if is possible to intercept a notification and stop it in order to be processed by the app in the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method but without raising any pop up in the device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't, except in special situations (e.g. Push notifications are used for Newsstand apps to notify them of new issues, but no popup is shown).

Comment: Then, there is no way to avoid the pop up in a normal app? Thanks.

Comment: Nope. Why do you want to block the popup anyway?

Comment: Because I'm planning use some "special" notifications sended from my own server in order to execute actions in the app. In example when a user is connected to the chat I wanna show an icon if the app is in foreground, but nothing when is in background. Or when a user creates a new channel I have to make some updates in the app but I don't want to show any pop up.

Comment: You'll probably just have to poll the server periodically when in the foreground for those specific notifications.